# How to let ripple enabled even when the MaterialButton is disabled?

Tags: android, material-components-android, materialbutton

Is there any way to let the ripple enabled on click action even if I disable the `MaterialButton`?

Comment: What it is the final goal? Why should a user press a disabled button?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap button with cardview and set card view clickable while setting button disabled

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean that, when set, determines the look and actions of the button when it is pressed.